# How to combine two mono-color images?

Tags: image, 3d

I need to write [an anaglyph images](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_image) program. Let say I have two mono-color images: red color one and cyan color one. How can I combines them into one to make an anaglyph image?

Please give me an advice.
Thank you.

P/s: I'm using C# program language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the images are RGB, use a Darken blending mode. If they're CMYK, use a Lighten blending mode.

For darken, take the lower value (Math.Min()) of each channel.
For lighten, take the higher one (Math.Max()).

```
//Darken pseudocode
for(int y=0;y<CompositionBitmap.Height;y++)
    for(int x=0;x<CompositionBitmap.Width;x++){
        CompositionBitmap[x,y].R=Math.Min(RedBitmap[x,y].R,CyanBitmap[x,y].R);
        CompositionBitmap[x,y].G=Math.Min(RedBitmap[x,y].G,CyanBitmap[x,y].G);
        CompositionBitmap[x,y].B=Math.Min(RedBitmap[x,y].B,CyanBitmap[x,y].B);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to use the ImageMagick [composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) utility to overlay the images. This method has no programming required.

Answer (score 1):

maybe set them at 50% alpha each then offset and copy them using a drawing surface

Comment: That won't handle the red/blue colouring that is needed.